# Emacs line no. in status bar set to '??'

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am having an issue in emacs (24) where occasionally the line no. in the status bar gets set to ??, e.g.

```
U:---   filename   All   (1000, 4)    (Conf[Unix])
```

switches to:

```
U:---   filename   All   (??, 4)    (Conf[Unix])
```

its a bit irritating and something I'd like to be able to prevent

Comment: as an aside - how do you get 2 question marks (on their own) in a question title? it beats me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the emacs documentation for line-number-mode:

"Line numbers do not appear for very large buffers and buffers
with very long lines; see variables `line-number-display-limit` and `line-number-display-limit-width`."

If you set line-number-display-limit to nil, you should always see a line number.

Comment: well spotted, it does seem to occur when files get big - either length or width ways..

Comment: Those limits are undoubtedly a performance measure, so you might not want to enforce this unnecessarily.

Comment: @phils yep, I have it set no nil and sometimes when viewing large files I have to wait for it to calculate the line number. I don't mind that though :)

Comment: possibly the use of linum-mode is more efficient for large files? I thought in some cases that this fix hadn't worked but I think I was just experiencing the latency mentioned due to the large file sizes i was dealing with